# How to properly read a CSV file?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, csv, python-multithreading

I need to read a CSV file containing account infos such as password and email for automating a login process on a website, I have a problem with multithreading, how can I let my script pick just one line and the respective rows for Thread-1 and a second one for Thread-2?

E.g.:

```
Link,Account,Password
...,aaa@aaa.com,Qwerty1234
...,aaa2@aaa.com,Qwerty12342
```

Made this but it reads all the rows and I can't use it...

```
csvfile =  open('verify.csv', newline='')
readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile)
header = next(readCSV)
if header != None:
    for row in readCSV:
        link = row[0]
        accemail = row[1]
        psw = row[2]
        print(link, accemail, psw)
```

Comment: This arrangement looks unusual to me. Why not read the file in the master thread and then pass the rows as parameters to the worker threads?

Comment: how could i do that? new to csv reading and multithreading

Comment: I still do not understand what's his purpose, i mean, how can i read it line by line or just focus each thread on different lines, like Thread-1=Line-1, Thread-2=Line-2

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "pick just one line and the respective rows" per thread?

Comment: I need to focus on line 1 for thread 1 and line 2 for thread 2

Comment: What do you mean by "focus" in a multithreaded program? Also, what about lines 3, 4, etc.

Comment: i just need to read stuff in line 1 for thread 1 and so on, not so difficult to understand tho

Comment: Too vague to understand, I'm afraid, which is reflected in the quantity (and quality) of the answers you've gotten thus far. Are you going to create a separate thread of each line of the file? How many lines can there be in a file?

Answer (score -1):

If you use `pandas.read_csv` it will pull in all the data in one go onto a `pandas dataframe`.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')

# do things with the data
print(data)
```

You can then extract whatever you like from the DataFrame.

Comment: One doesn't need `pandas` to read the data in from a csv file.

Comment: That is correct, there are other alternatives, but pandas has a whole variety of useful features if working with the data, so is convenient.  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html . And in this case it reads the data in 2 lines of code (including the import).

Comment: my goal is to read 1 line for each thread

Comment: Indeed, one of the other alternatives is Python's built-in the `csv` module. It's not convenient if you don't already have it installed and aren't familiar with it — in this case I'd call it total overkill (as well as likely beyond the OP's current ability to comprehend).

Comment: Being a built-in is a good point @martineau and accepted. I proposed this method only because it is cleaner. The builtin `csv` module requires more lines of code to achieve the same result. Some imports are better (more convenient) than the built-ins...

Comment: It can be done with two statements using the `csv` module. Regardless, see [Am I overkilling questions with solutions that are too complex for the OP to understand?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261402/am-i-overkilling-questions-with-solutions-that-are-too-complex-for-the-op-to-und) to understand my point.